# "Tidal waves are the result of an abrupt shift in the underwater movement of the Earth". Are 'shift' and 'movements' synonyms?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

My book explains that "Tidal waves are the result of an abrupt shift in the underwater movement of the Earth".

It seems to me that the words *shift* and *movement* have similar meanings in this sentence. Could you explain the differences of those words in this context? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Shift* means *a change*.

It may mean a move, some movement that displaced a thing that normally was in one position, and placed it in another. But a train on a railway track in the middle of 6-hour journey is not shifting. It may shift tracks - move from one track to the other, but it's not shifting from 786th kilometer to 787th.

*A shift in the movement* means the movement changes. The tectonic plates moving 3cm a year for past millennium suddenly skipped 2 meters. That was a shift that caused the waves. The movement was building tension, storing energy, and once something snapped, the rapid change occurs - the movement caused the shift.

Comment: Although technically correct, with respect to tectonic movement, this sentence does sound redundant to me, and I would find "shift in the underwater configuration" less surprising.

Answer (score 3):

"Shift" means "change" in your textbook's sentence. When driving a car with a standard transmission, the driver has to *shift* gears, which means *change* gears.